# Linq to XML is Reducing File Size

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file that begins at 1,030KB. After I run my code, which is adding an element to a section of the xml file, the file reduces to a size of 580kb. I think this might be a reason why a secondary application reading this file, cannot read the newly generated file. I am not sure why this is happening. Is there a way to stop Linq to XML from compressing the file?

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(cust_file);

XElement parentXElement = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("LastLayout2/CommandBars");
XElement refXElement = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("LastLayout2/CommandBars/CommandBar[@Title = 'Standard']/Controls");

XElement temp = refXElement.XPathSelectElement("Control[@Parameter = 'GLOBAL!QMS_Launcher.Main']");

if (temp == null)
{
XElement newElement = new XElement("Control");
XAttribute classAt = new XAttribute("Class", "CXTPControlButton");
XAttribute idAt = new XAttribute("Id", "0");
XAttribute paramAt = new XAttribute("Parameter", "GLOBAL!QMS_Launcher.Main");
XAttribute custIdAt = new XAttribute("CustomIconId", "68267");

XElement customIcon = new XElement("CustomIcon");
XElement icon = new XElement("Icon");
XAttribute width = new XAttribute("Width", "16");
XAttribute data = new XAttribute("Data", "ABAAAAAAFCAAAAAAEDAAICAAAAAAABAAAAAAABAAAAAABAAAACAADAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPPAAAAPPAAAAPPAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPGAAAAAAJNAAAAAAFCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANAAAAAAAHFAAAAAACHAAAAAAALAAAAAAPPAAAAAAJPAAAAAAHCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPFAAAAAAJOAAAAAAPPAAAAAAPPAAAAAAPPAAAAAALOABJAAACGDNJIAADNGJCGAAGJGAEAAAGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGDAAAAAANPAAAAAAMPAAAAAAJLAAAAAAMHAAAAAAFFAAAAAAODAAAAAAAKMGFEAAEIPPGKAAPPPHDFAAPHAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEMAAAAAAPPAAAAAAPGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANGAAAAAAPPCBMAAAIFIHOEAAIHJFJDAAJFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOOAAAAAAEPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPHAAAAAAPPGBOAAAKGILHHAAILILHHAAILJJEGAAJJFEMCAAFEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEPAAAAAAEOAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHJAAAAAAPPGCJBAAAHPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPMPEKAAMPPDJCAAPDAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOMAAAAAAPPAAAAAAJBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALLAAAAAAPPBCFBAAKFILHHAAILILHHAAILILHHAAILILHHAAILKGFEAAKGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANJAAAAAAPPAAAAAANMAAAAAABCAAAAAANBAAAAAABIAAAAAAPPAAAAAAHOAEKCAAMEIHOEAAIHIHOEAAIHIHOEAAIHIHOEAAIHJGDEAAJGGCJBAAGCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFBAAAAAADOAAAAAAPPAAAAAAPPAAAAAAPPAAAAAAPPAAAAAALPMAIAAAHGNOKJAANOPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPOPFKAAOPKFKDAAKFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKBAAAAAANJAAAAAABPAAAAAABPAAAAAAAMJBPAAALELMEIAALMPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPINMIAAINAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");

icon.Add(width, data);

customIcon.Add(icon);
newElement.Add(customIcon);

newElement.Add(classAt, idAt, paramAt, custIdAt);

                    xDoc.Element("LastLayout2").Element("CommandBars").Elements("CommandBar")
                        .FirstOrDefault(item => item.Attribute("Title") != null && item.Attribute("Title").Value == "Standard")
                        .Element("Controls").Add(newElement);

xDoc.Save(cust_file);
```

Comment: May be your original file has formatting, *(white spaces)*, and your newly generated file doesn't.

Comment: I ran a WinDiff against the newly generated file and the original file. I see that my newly generated file adds a space before the end of a closing tag. For example, original file has '/>' and mine has ' />'. Line count is the same before and after as well.

Comment: Encoding difference?  Perhaps UTF-16 to UTF8. That could halve the size.

Comment: Maybe...how do I change the encoding when writing to xml?

Comment: Create an `XmlWriterSettings`, set [`XmlWriterSettings.Encoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.encoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as appropriate, then [create an `XmlWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162618%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and pass it to [`XDocument.Save()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336977%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: It's possible. But that's not really the issue. The XDocument.Save will generate a valid XML doc - so the real problem is why the other application is not accepting it. Do you have control over the secondary app?

Comment: What happens if you load the XML into an `XDocument` and save it back without modifying it?  Does the file size decrease?  Can the 3rd party app read it or not?

Comment: @Baldrick no I do not have control over the secondary app. However, your previous answer did work. Now that I am encoding it as UTF16, the application is reading it properly. Thanks for the help! If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Ok.. nobody answered, so I've done so anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like an encoding issue. You're probably saving down as a different encoding to the original document, and different from what the target application is expecting. Hence the change in file size.

It's possible to change the encoding used for the save as described by dbc above:

> Create an XmlWriterSettings, set XmlWriterSettings.Encoding as
>   appropriate, then create an XmlWriter and pass it to XDocument.Save().